# Steps in using a java third party library from clojure

Tags: java, swing, clojure, leiningen

I am very close to being able to do this. I chose [JDatePicker](https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker) to see what it takes. Steps:

```
1) git clone https://github.com/JDatePicker/JDatePicker
2) cd JDatePicker
3) mvn package
```

Then installed [localrepo](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-localrepo) Don't know if there is an easier way but this seems to be the way pointed to by others on the internet.

```
4) vi  ~/.lein/profiles.clj
5) {:user {:plugins [[lein-localrepo "0.5.3"]]}}
```

Inside JDatePicker directory where the .jar file is located, used localrepo to give jdatepicker a coordinate so that lein projects can use it. I am using lein version:

```
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure/jdatepickertest $ lein version
Leiningen 2.5.0 on Java 1.7.0_72 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
idf@idf-Satellite-C55t-A ~/Documents/clojure/jdatepickertest $ 

6) lein localrepo install jdatepicker-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org/jdatepicker 2.0.0
```

Created a new clojure project to see if I can access it

```
7) lein new jdatepickertest
8) cd jdatepickertest
```

modified the project.clj file and added [org/jdatepicker     "2.0.0"] to the dependencies section

```
9)    
 (defproject jdatepickertest "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"   :description
 "FIXME: write description"   :url "http://example.com/FIXME"  
 :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
 :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}   
 :dependencies
         [
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org/jdatepicker     "2.0.0"]
         ] )
```

did a lein deps which returned nothing so assumed all went well

```
10) lein deps
```

launched a repl inside jdatepickertest directory

```
11) lein repl
```

***Now I try to use jdatepicker from clojure but I can't seem to access it?***

```
12) 
nREPL server started on port 43286 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:43286
REPL-y 0.3.5, nREPL 0.2.6
Clojure 1.6.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_72-b14
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e
user=> (clojure-version)
"1.6.0"
user=> (require '[jdatepicker :as datepicker])
FileNotFoundException Could not locate jdatepicker__init.class or jdatepicker.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
user=> (require '[org.jdatepicker :as datepicker])

FileNotFoundException Could not locate org/jdatepicker__init.class or org/jdatepicker.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)
user=>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need lein-localrepo for this, it would suffice to specify the maven coordinates in your project.clj

```
[org.jdatepicker/jdatepicker "1.3.4"]
```

`require` is for clojure namespaces. Java classes will be looked up in the classpath when used, and you can use `import` if you prefer to use the unqualified class name.

```
(import org.jdatepicker.JDatePicker)
```

After that you can proceed to use `JDatePicker` via interop as you would any other java library.

Comment: Quick question,how do I instantiate a JDatePicker inside a panel and display it?

Comment: The guide at [clojure.org](http://clojure.org/java_interop) is pretty good. Look up what constructor you want to use, and invoke it from Clojure. `(JDatePicker. <args>)`

Comment: Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304476/simple-java-interop-from-clojure

Comment: For starters, you didn't import the class you are actually using. Check out the docs for java interop, it isn't super complex.

Comment: See changes. Everything is obvious once you know how to do it. This is a bit confusing.

Comment: I didn't say anything was obvious. Your mistakes show an unfamiliarity with basic concepts in Clojure java interop, and that is the best intro I know of to the topic.